# How to add a path to the system path in MySQL Workbench for Mac (Big Sur)

Tags: python, mysql, macos, mysql-workbench, sys.path

I was using Catalina OS with MySQL Workbench for Mac, which worked fine for old iMac of mine.  But when I recently bought a new Mac with Big Sur OS and installed MySQL Workbench, it gave me the follow import error:

```
Fatal Python error: initfsencoding: unable to load the file system codec, sys.path = ['/Applications/MySQLWorkbench.app/Contents/Resources/libraries', '/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python37.zip', '/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7', '/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/lib-dynload']
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'encodings'

Current thread 0x000000011ac12e00 (most recent call first):
```

I knew that this was due to system path improperly configured as my python version is 3.8.  So I added a path to the system path in bash_profile.  See below:

```
export PYTHONPATH=~/Library/Python/3.8/lib/python/site-packages:$PYTHONPATH

export PATH=/usr/bin:$PATH
```

The resulting sys.path in python shell gave me this:

```
Python 3.8.2 (default, Nov  4 2020, 21:23:28) 
[Clang 12.0.0 (clang-1200.0.32.28)] on darwin
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import sys
>>> print(sys.path)
['', '/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/Library/Frameworks/Python3.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python38.zip', '/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/Library/Frameworks/Python3.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8', '/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/Library/Frameworks/Python3.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/lib-dynload', '/Users/phillipkim/Library/Python/3.8/lib/python/site-packages', '/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/Library/Frameworks/Python3.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages']
```

I sourced the file and restarted the computer.  However, I get the same error message when I try to run MySQL Workbench.  I found the following [website](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/mysql-shell/8.0/en/mysql-shell-creating-startup-scripts.html) that explains where to update the system environment for MySQL Workbench, but it only shows examples for Windows and Linux OSs.  How do I add a path to the system path for MySQL Workbench for Mac?  Much appreciated.

Comment:  Please post code, errors, sample data or textual output here as plain-text, not as images that can be hard to read, can’t be copy-pasted to help test code or use in answers, and are barrier to those who depend on screen readers or translation tools. You can edit your question to add the code in the body of your question. For easy formatting use the `{}` button to mark blocks of code, or indent with four spaces for the same effect. The contents of a **screenshot can’t be searched, run as code, or copied and edited to create a solution.**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found the following solution: https://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=102364

MySQLWorkbench need Python3.7 Framework in `/Library/Frameworks/`

1. Run `brew install python@3.7`
2. Then, run `sudo cp -r /usr/local/Cellar/python@3.7/3.7.9_3/Frameworks/Python.framework /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework`
3. Finally, open MySQLWorkbench and it works.

Or you can just create a symlink to the entire file (thx to @Phillip1982)

`sudo ln -s /usr/local/Cellar/python@3.7/3.7.10_1/Frameworks/Python.framework /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework`

Comment: This worked beautifully.  Mine was 3.7.10_1 by the way and I used a symlink instead of copying the entire file.  sudo ln -s /usr/local/Cellar/python@3.7/3.7.10_1/Frameworks/Python.framework /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework

Comment: I had a similar issue: MySQLWorkbench was looking for python2.7 in `/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework` when it was really in `/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework`. Calling `sudo ln -s /System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework` worked wonderfully.

Answer (score 4):

**Problem**

[image]

```
Termination Reason: Namespace DYLD, 
Code 1 Library missing Library not loaded: 
'/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Python' 
Referenced from: '/Applications/MySQLWorkbench.app/Contents/MacOS/MySQLWorkbench' 
Reason: tried: '/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Python'
```

**Solution**

The method explained over [here](https://liam.page/en/2022/04/01/fix-missing-Python2-7-on-macOS-Monterey-12-3/) worked well for me. So the issue is that `python 2.7` got removed from `Mac 12.3`, which affects applications like `Workbench`.

To make them work again, you need to download `Python 2.7.x` from official download [link](https://www.python.org/ftp/python/2.7.18/python-2.7.18-macosx10.9.pkg). Then install it and your tool should begin to operate.

Answer (score 0):

I got the same issue after upgrading my macOS to Ventura. I had fixed this error simply by downloading the latest [MYSQLWORKBENCH](https://dev.mysql.com/downloads/workbench/) application and re-installing on my laptop